# Blender : Create custom physics via scripts

Tags: python, scripting, blender

Blender provides options to enable different kinds of physics for objects - cloth, fluid etc. I'd like to add a custom physics model to this. Let's say I create a physics model "My Physics" and provide it as an option under the physics tab - along with the other existing options. Then, when an object is assigned "My Physics" as a modifier, the object will behave as modeled by my script. For example, if I were to provide a custom cloth simulation algorithm and assign it to a mesh, then the object should use this algorithm.

I basically want to test some physics algorithms and use blenders rendering and other systems for that, but the physics part will come from my code.

Is something like this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you might not even need to go that deep just use python to control some objects is perfectly doable and i guess easier.

Though if you like to realy add something to blender, not just your testing but say a planatary addon or so with specific gravity rules, then hangout on the python dev irc channels.
https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Communication/Contact/IRC